# How to monitor download progress via SKStoreProductViewController in iOS 6+?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, itunes, storekit, itunes-store

I've just added InApp downloads via SKStoreProductViewController.  I'm wondering if there is a way I can get the download status of the item that is being downloaded.  I would ideally like to monitor the download and when it is complete, I would like to execute some code.

I've looked through the documentation but there's nothing listed on there.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that.
You don't even get notified if the user has chosen to install the item.

It's very unfortunate.

Comment: So what exactly happens when the user buys an item?  Do they have to press "cancel" to close the menu?

Comment: Either the user chooses to install the app, waits for it to install and presses open to start it or the user presses cancel (regardless of  whether he has chosen to install it) and you get the only delegate call, prompting you to get rid of the controller.

Comment: Oh that's not helpful.  I was hoping the Cancel button would change to a "Done" or something.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit dirty, but if you are trying to download one of your own apps, you can put [customs url](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html) on them, and then loop with

```
- (BOOL)canOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
```

and when it will return you "true", it means that your application has been installed.

Comment: That's a neat trick but I'm trying to download something from iTunes.